# HTML form submit a single item from a collection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view with a view model that has a collection of sellers. I loop over all of the sellers to render the list. Here is the view model:

```
public class SellersPartialViewModel
{
    public IList<OrderViewModel> Sellers { get; set; }
}
```

In the partial view I'm using Html.BeginCollectionItem("Sellers") when I loop through the collection and here is my code for the partial (FYI I've stripped away a lot of useless code that doesn't need to be seen):

```
<div id="sellers-list">
    @{
        var i = 0;
        while (i < Model.Sellers.Count) { 
            var seller = Model.Sellers[i];

                using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Video.PurchaseShares(), purchaseSharesAjaxOptions, new { @class = "seller-form", id = "seller-form-" + i })) {
                    @using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Sellers")) {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => seller.Qty, new { @class = "buyer-qty" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => seller.Qty)

                       <input class="buyer-qty-submit" name="Qty" type="hidden" value="" />
                       <button type="submit">Buy</button>
                    }
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
</div>
```

This works fine for rendering the partial and getting the client-side validation working 
however I want each seller to have the inputs named `qty` and `orderId` for a controller action called `PurchaseShares(int orderId, int qty)`.

The only problem is the form is being submitted with the odd GUID like `Sellers[5b5fd3f2-12e0-4e72-b289-50a69aa06158].seller.Qty` which I understand is correct for submitting collections but I don't need to do that.

Right now I have some Javascript that is updating the `class="buyer-qty"` with whatever they select and it works fine but there has got to be a better way of doing this, no?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper if you don't want to submit collections?

You could have a partial representing your Order collection item (`_Order.cshtml`):

```
@model OrderViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Qty, new { @class = "buyer-qty" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Qty)
```

And in your main view simply loop through your collection property and render the partial for each element:

```
@model SellersPartialViewModel

<div id="sellers-list">
    @foreach (var seller in Model.Sellers)
    {
        using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Video.PurchaseShares(), purchaseSharesAjaxOptions, new { @class = "seller-form" }))
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Order", seller)
            <button type="submit">Buy</button>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Now your controller action you are submitting to could directly work with the corresponding view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PurchaseShares(OrderViewModel order)
{
    ...
}
```

because:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PurchaseShares(int orderId, int qty)
{
    ...
}
```

kinda looks uglier to me but it would also work if you prefer it.

Also please notice that I have deliberately removed the `Qty` hidden field shown in your code as it would conflict with the input element with the same name. Also don't forget to include an input field for the `orderId` argument that your controller action is expecting or when you submit it could bomb. Also you could send it as part of the `routeValues` argument of the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper if you don't want to include it as an input field.

Comment: This looks promising I will have to try it out. I was wondering though why do I have to create a partial for OrderViewModel? Does Html.Partial do something behind the scenes that can't be done in the main partial view?

Comment: When using a partial the name of your input field will be `Qty` instead of `seller.Qty`. So if you don't use a partial you will have to decorate your `OrderViewModel` action argument on the `PurchaseShares` action with the `[Bind]` attribute in order to specify the `seller` prefix.